# Trying to access state in form handler gives default state not updated state in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a component with two states `name` and `email` whose initial values are coming from previous route ,
the state does change on using setter methods but , when i try to access the state values in from handler it always gives the default values
Here is the code

```
const EditProfileScreen = (props) => {
const [name, setName] = useState(props.navigation.getParam('name'))
const [email, setEmail] = useState(props.navigation.getParam('email'))
const nameHandler = (text) => {
    setName(text)
}
const emailHandler = text => {
    setEmail(text)
}
const handleSubmit =() => {
        console.log(name)
 // It returns the default value not the updated one

 }
 return (
<View>
                <TextInput style={styles.input} onChangeText={emailHandler} value={email} />
                <TextInput style={styles.input} onChangeText={nameHandler} value={name} />
</View>
)}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is happening, but as a workaround you can introduce the `useEffect` hook:

```
const [name, setName] = useState('')
const [email, setEmail] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
  setName(props.navigation.getParam('name'))
  setEmail(props.navigation.getParam('email'))
}, []);
```